# Updating a geometry inside a mesh does nothing

Tags: three.js

I am using THREE.JS rev 49.

My program needs to update a mesh by changing it's geometry. 
Unfortunately the display does not seem to update.

Here is my code :

```
// theObject is an array of associatives :

// {
//     object1: {mesh: undefined/THREE.mesh, mat: THREE.Material, geo: THREE.Geometry}
//     object2: {mesh: undefined/THREE.mesh, mat: THREE.Material, geo: THREE.Geometry}
//     ...
// }

// In my function, theObject[i].mesh geometry must change to be theObject[i].geo.


for(i in theObjects) {

    //*
    if ( theObjects[i].mesh == undefined) {
        theObjects[i].mesh = new THREE.Mesh(theObjects[i].geo, theObjects[i].mat);

        theObjects[i].mesh.geometry.dynamic = true;
        theObjects[i].geo.verticesNeedUpdate = true;

        scenePostsurgery.add(theObjects[i].mesh);
    }  else
        theObjects[i].mesh.geometry.vertices = theObjects[i].geo.vertices;

}
```

Do I have to add something else ?

/Oragon

Answer (score 18, accepted):

If I understood correctly you are updating vertices here:

```
else{
        theObjects[i].mesh.geometry.vertices = theObjects[i].geo.vertices;  
}
```

Try to change this code to :

```
else{
         theObjects[i].mesh.geometry.dynamic = true;
         theObjects[i].mesh.geometry.vertices = theObjects[i].geo.vertices;  
         theObjects[i].mesh.geometry.verticesNeedUpdate = true;
    }
```

In `if(){}` you create a mesh and in `else{}` you update so `dynamic = true` and `verticesNeedUpdate = true` you need to set to mesh which is in `else{}`.

Comment: Thank you Uhura. I though `verticesNeedUpdate` was a permanent option. :)

Comment: Note that since r67, `geometry.dynamic=true` is not needed anymore: https://threejs.org/docs/#manual/introduction/How-to-update-things

Answer (score 3):

When changing the entire geometry, I think the easiest way is to remove the old one (scene.remove(geometry), then add the new one (scene.add(geometry)). I think the cost of modifying the mesh and geometry parameters and properties is the same as adding a new one, although adding is much easier and saves a lot of headache!

Comment: make sure if you use `scene.remove(mesh)`, you also call `mesh.geometry.dispose()`, `mesh.material.dispose()` and `mesh.texture.dispose()` else you'll get memory leaks I think (r71)

Comment: mesh.geometry.dispose is not a function