# Three.js: Completely change object's Geometry

Tags: three.js

*edited*

How to replace object's Geometry leaving object itself (and scene hierarchy) intact?

Direct assignment of `mesh.geometry` to new `Geometry` and `needsUpdate = true` doesn't work in my code.

This is the code example from three.js site (http://threejs.org/docs/#Manual/Introduction/Creating_a_scene) with my small additions marked by comments "my 1", "my 2" and "my3".

```
        var scene = new THREE.Scene();
        var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(75, window.innerWidth/window.innerHeight, 0.1, 1000);

        var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
        renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
        document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

        camera.position.z = 5;

        var geomCube = new THREE.CubeGeometry(1,1,1),
            geomSphere = new THREE.SphereGeometry(1);

        var material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({color: 0x20a0e0, wireframe: true, wireframeLinewidth: 3});

        var mesh = new THREE.Mesh(geomCube, material);

        scene.add(mesh);

        // ******** my 1 ********
        mesh.geometry = geomSphere;
        mesh.geometry.needsUpdate = true;

        // ******** my 3 ********
        function onclickTest()
            {
            mesh.geometry = geomCube;
            mesh.geometry.needsUpdate = true;
            }


        var cnt = 300;

        var render = function () {
            requestAnimationFrame(render);

            mesh.rotation.x += 0.01;
            mesh.rotation.y += 0.01;

            renderer.render(scene, camera);

            // ******** my 2 ********
            if ( !cnt-- )
                {
                mesh.geometry = geomCube;
                mesh.geometry.needsUpdate = true;
                }

        };

        render();
```

The code "my 1" works, it changes initial cube to sphere. But code "my 2" causes error inside three.js. I also placed the same code in a button's onclick handle, not in the render loop ("my 3"), but with the same result: it fails.

Could somebody tell about good method of Geometry replacement?

p.s.
In principle, we can place "dummy" nodes on the place of Meshes in the scene hierarchy. Mesh nodes can be linked to dummy ones as childs. In this case Mesh removal and creation will not affect scene's structure. But I don't like this solution, it doesn't look naturally.

Comment: cant you just use Three.CubeGeometry and after one object is done loading, replace the geometry-subObject of the Mesh and do Mesh.geometry.needsUpdate = true;?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15384078/updating-a-geometry-inside-a-mesh-does-nothing

Comment: Also, i can't see why exchanging meshes destroys the sceneGraph or alters it, if it is done right.

Comment: Thanks, GuyGood. When I do this 'mesh = new THREE.Mesh(geomCube, material);
scene.add(mesh);  
mesh.geometry = geomNew;
mesh.geometry.needsUpdate = true;' it works. When I call last 2 lines from another place (in my onclick handle) all fails inside three.js code. I'm new to javascript too, so I need to additionally check my variables.

Comment: @GuyGood "why ... destroys the scene graph...". I meant geometry change via its deletion and creation. I met this advise somewhere in Google. I hope that needsUpdate = true will help, I need to experiment more.

Comment: " Geometry changes is not good because it removes child nodes and destroys scene hierarchy." said you. And I say that this is not the case if you do it properly and it is way easier to just replace a mesh instead of keeping track of all the geometry stuff i guess but well, good luck :)