# Changing a three.js object's geometry

Tags: javascript, three.js

I am trying to change the geometry of some objects in a three.js scene. I have an almost-working piece of code where a mouse click triggers the change, but got the following problem: the (rendered) shape is only changed on the *first* mouse click, even though the geometry is also successfully modified by each following clicks. Using v66 or v68 of three.js library, if it is relevant.

I read [Three.js: Completely change object's Geometry](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19977074) and [Updating a geometry inside a mesh does nothing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15384078) but couldn't get my code to work so far.

Relevant parts of my code:

```
var count = 0, item, geometry;
var geoms = [new THREE.SphereGeometry(2), new THREE.BoxGeometry(3, 3, 3)];


function init() {

    geometry = geoms[count];
    item = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
    scene.add(item);

}

// Mouse click listener.
function handleClick(event) {
    count = 1 - count;
    geometry = geoms[count];
    item.geometry = geometry;

    /* With that next line, on the first click, the sphere
     * becomes a cube (as intended), but further clicks don't
     * change the view anymore, even though item.geometry is
     * modified.
     */
    item.geometry.buffersNeedUpdate = true;

    /* If I try next line instead, I got the following error:
     * "TypeError: l.geometryGroupsList is undefined"
     * from three.js.
     */
    // item.geometry.verticesNeedUpdate = true;
}
```

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/hzmj74gb/) is a jsfiddle of a (non-)working example. There is a sphere on screen, a click will make it a cube. Further clicks are supposed to switch between sphere and cube, but nothing change on-screen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know exactly why this happens. It is unable to update geometry of mesh by a geometry object once used.

`.clone()` works in this case.

```
item.geometry.dispose();
item.geometry = geometry.clone();
```

`dispose()` previous geometry object to prevent memory leaks.

There would be a better solution.

Comment: Thank you for that answer.  So is it a bug in the library (and if so, is it worth reporting)?

Comment: This is supposed not to be a bug. Before rendering starts, geometry must be translated to ArrayBuffers, this operation in pretty costly. That's why you must update geometry.

Answer (score 0):

i found this code to run the fastest:

```
  item.geometry.computeFaceNormals();
  item.geometry.computeVertexNormals();
  item.geometry.normalsNeedUpdate = true;
  item.geometry.verticesNeedUpdate = true;
  item.geometry.dynamic = true;
```