# ThreeJS, Updating mesh.geometry at runtime

Tags: three.js

Considering a scene and 3 `BoxBufferGeometries`, I don't want to re-render the scene (`drawObjects` is called once, the 'first' time), but rather update it (`updateScene` is called on user action for example), the following code sucessfully updates the color and texture material attributes for all the objects of the scene, but only seems to affect one of the  3 objects when it comes to mesh.geometry transformation (one becomes as sphere, the 2 other remains squares), why? ([live example](https://still-bayou-39915.herokuapp.com/))

```
drawObjects = (options) ->
    map = (new (THREE.TextureLoader)).load(options.texture)
    map.wrapS = map.wrapT = THREE.RepeatWrapping
    map.anisotropy = 16
    material = new (THREE.MeshToonMaterial)(
        color: options.color
        map: map
        transparent: true
        side: THREE.DoubleSide)

    geometry = new THREE.BoxBufferGeometry( 20, 20, 20 )

    i = 0
    while i < 3
        object = new (THREE.Mesh)(geometry, material, (color: Math.random() * 0xffffff))
        object.position.x = Math.random() * 800 - 400
        object.position.y = Math.random() * 800 - 400
        object.position.z = Math.random() * 800 - 400

        object.setGeometry = ->
            geometry = new THREE.SphereGeometry(20)
            object.geometry = geometry
            return

        object.setTexture = (texture) ->
            object.material.map = new THREE.TextureLoader().load( texture )
            return

        object.setColor = (color) ->
            object.material.color = new THREE.Color(color)
            return

        scene.add object
        i++

updateScene = (options) ->
    @scene.traverse (object) ->
        if object.isMesh == true
            object.setColor(options.color)
            object.setTexture(options.texture)
            object.setGeometry()
            return
```

I tried few other approches aswell, the first was about updating vertices (like indicated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15384078/updating-a-geometry-inside-a-mesh-does-nothing)) but it doesn't work since BoxGeometry do no have vertices. Then I tied to add a few options such as, but without success.

```
# object.geometry.dynamic = true
# object.geometry.buffersNeedUpdate = true
# object.updateMatrix()
```

The second one was using `object dispose` basically making a clone of the original, like advised [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25766981/changing-a-three-js-objects-geometry) dispose the original mesh and replace it with its clone such as but it didn't work in my case since I have functions attached to this object I'll need to re-use. Maybe I did it wrong:

```
object.geometry.dispose();
object.geometry = geometry.clone();
```

I bet there is a way to achieve this kind mesh.geometry transformation and apply it to every object while traversing the scene, but can't find how.

Kind regards

Answer (score 0):

Ended up doing it with a function out of the object itself:

```
setGeometries = (geometry) ->
    @scene.traverse (object) ->
        if object
            object.geometry = geometry
            object.geometry.buffersNeedUpdate = true
            return
        return
    return
```

Where `geometry` is something like `new THREE.[Primitive]BuffferGeometry`. Works for me.