# Set transparency of face by index in THREE.js

Tags: three.js

I've managed to set the colour of a mesh face using:

```
geometry.faces[i].color.setHex('0xff00ff');
```

Is there a function to set the transparency to true and opacity to say 0.5?
I'm sure there is one, just have no idea of the syntax.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Actually, you cannot achieve that by changing your geometry. Because transparency controlled by materials.

But there's way to do this.

First, each face has `materialIndex` ([Face manual](http://threejs.org/docs/#Reference/Core/Face3)).

Next, Each mesh, drawn within three.js scene has material. And there's special material of type `THREE.MeshFaceMaterial` ([MeshFaceMaterial manual](http://threejs.org/docs/#Reference/Materials/MeshFaceMaterial)), which takes array of materials as argument.

When faces are drawn, three.js renderer takes face's materialIndex and uses corresponding material from this material array or, if mesh contains single material type.

So you could do something like:

```
var opacMaterial = new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial({
  transparent:true, 
  opacity:0.7
});
var solidMaterial = new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial({
  transparent:false, 
  color:new THREE.Color(1,0,0)
});

var mesh = new THREE.Mesh(
  geometry, 
  new THREE.MultiMaterial([solidMaterial, opacMaterial])
 );
```

By default, if your geometry have `materialIndex == 0` for each faces, you will see solidMaterial drawn.

If you want to make it transparent do something like this;

```
geometry.faces[i].materialIndex = 1;
```

Don't forget to update geometry in mesh: ([How to update geometry in mesh question.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15384078/updating-a-geometry-inside-a-mesh-does-nothing))

Also, aware, if you have `materialIndex` in your faces greater than length of material array, you will get awkward error inside of deep of THREE.js

Comment: Frankly saying,  I made a typo in this answer. I just fixed it.